# Does a glaive count as a sword and a halberd an axe for the purpose of magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

If the party earns a Dragon Slayer Sword, it can be a type of weapon used by one of the party members but it says it must be a sword, so would a Glaive count?

Comment: Related: [Do scimitars and rapiers count as swords for the magic items in the 5E DMG?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91583/do-scimitars-and-rapiers-count-as-swords-for-the-magic-items-in-the-5e-dmg)

Comment: The top answer to that question seems to answer this one quite well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, glaives aren't swords, and halberds aren't axes. Putting a blade on the end of a pole makes it fundamentally a different weapon. After all, a spear is not a dagger!

That said, if *you're* the DM (and you're not playing in Adventurers League), you can make substitutions in published adventures' treasure as you see fit. If you want to have the party find a Dragon Slaying Glaive instead of a Dragon Slaying Sword, do it. That sounds pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

By strict RAW, a glaive can't be Dragon Slayer. On pg. 206 of the DMG are Sword of Life Stealing and Sword of Sharpness; Life Stealing has the (any sword) tag, while Sharpness (any sword that deals slashing damage). So, a shortsword could be Life Stealing, but not Sharpness. That said, there is nothing stopping the Game Master from tweaking the RAW to accommodate Rule of Cool. Also, it's a bit of an oversight that there aren't more clear definitions of the weapons like in 4e (i.e. does a scimitar or rapier count as a (sword) even though sword is not in their name or properties)