# Is a dual-wielding Eldritch Knight fighter workable?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, fighter, two-weapon-fighting

As I understand it an Eldritch Knight has the ability to cast a spell and attack as a Bonus Action.
Two-weapon fighting allows you to attack normally with one hand and take a Bonus Action to attack with the off-hand.

Now it seems to me that you cannot benefit from both and they are redundant abilities. Despite this I've read posts suggesting that dual wielding eldritch knights are a good combo.

My question: **Is it worth it to combine both or should I stick to one** — going either eldritch knight with one weapon and the dueling fighting style, or two-weapon fighting with one of the other fighter archetypes?

New to 5e but experienced in other RPGs if that matters.
I'll be playing my first game of 5e soon and I planned to play a variant human two-weapon-fighting fighter with the Dual Wielder feat using a longsword + handaxe as my starting outfit. But as the first one-shot game might lead to a campaign, I want to start out "right" and the eldritch knight sounds interesting.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how the Q&A site works, and how to get the most from your participation here.  Thanks for the question, and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Welcome! I hope yo'll take the [tour] at some point. But if you do, you'll notice there's no real "manual" to the site, just a few broad guidelines. The rest just comes from participating and then getting prodded in one direction or another by someone who's been around.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two-weapon fighting is itself, not worth it. Straight out of the box, using a two-handed weapon does better damage. See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44241/15469) for details. By the time you add in the damage boost from the Great Weapon Master feat, a two-handed weapon crushes two-weapon fighting completely.

It ges worse for two-weapon fighting, though, because the whole benefit of two-weapon fighting is being able to attack with a bonus action in addition to your regular attacks. However, a two-handed weapon (glaive or halberd) can do that anyway, thanks to the Polearm Master feat.

For most characters, getting both these feats is a little impractical. But as a variant human, you get a feat right out of the box, and as a Fighter, you get extras along the way. So this is completely attainable.

**Everything above is optimization advice.** A two-handed weapon does far better damage than two-weapon fighting, but if you want to use two-weapon fighting, you should go for it.

Now, the question you really wanted to know - is attacking with your action and then with a bonus action worth it, since you can cast a spell with your action and then attack with your bonus action?

And the answer is yes, absolutely. Attacking will usually be a better use of your action than casting a spell. For example, at level 13, you could cast *fireball* for 8d6 damage, averaging 28 damage. However, if you instead attacked with your action, you could attack 3 times, dealing 1d10 + 15 damage each time - for an average of **61.5** damage - more than twice as much.

This assmes that you're using the advice I gave above. If you're dual-wielding, you could attack 3 times for 1d8 + 5 damage, averaging 28.5 damage. Still better than casting *fireball*, but only just.

So why use spells? Well, the easiest example is casting *haste* on yourself, giving you an extra attack every round, as well as some other benefits. But you're likely to do that on the first round of a combat, and then spend the rest of the time attacking.

Comment: I agree with most of the points here, except Fireball can deal more situational damage, any time you are fighting more than one enemy. For instance, if you happen to catch 5 enemies with your fireball then your average damage has increased to 140.  The situational AoE is, I think, one of the best use cases for EK spell slots (not including RP and flavor of course). 

But otherwise I agree, when facing one or two enemies, or if too many comrades are in the are of effect, simply 3 attacks with a great weapon/polearm will almost always be better.