# Is allowing an Eldritch Knight with Dual Wielder feat to summon both weapons at once unbalanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, balance, two-weapon-fighting

RAW it is not possible to summon both of your bonded weapons as part of the same Bonus Action.  The [Eldritch Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#EldritchKnight)'s Weapon Bond feature (PHB, p. 75) states:

> Once you have bonded a weapon to yourself [...] you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn [...] You can have up to two bonded weapons but can summon only one at a time with your bonus action.

Meanwhile the [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/dual-wielder) feat (PHB, p. 165) says:

> You can draw or stow two one-handed weapons when you would normally be able to draw or stow only one.

It doesn't sound unreasonable to me to allow this (because you've taken the necessary feat to do so), but I may be missing something unbalancing.

**Would it be unbalanced to allow Eldritch Knights who have the Dual Wielder feat to summon both bonded weapons as their Bonus Action?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## It will not cause balance problems

Dual wielding itself is [quite weak](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130233/9552), and the bonus you provide is minor.

It will not change game balance noticeably, dual wielding is still the weakest option from level 5.

Comment: What do you mean weakest from level 5? Like it is good until 5 then drops in worth?

Comment: @bubbajake00 this is exactly what I mean, except it is good until level 4. From next level on, it is the worst.

Comment: I'm not sure that "weakest option" is correct here. One of the weaker options, sure but I would add some support if you are claiming that dual wielding is the weakest option. Also weakest for who? Out of what options?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose weakest for DPR.